# Phalcon Undefined namespace Phalcon

Tags: php, phpstorm, phalcon

I'm making project using Phalcon PHP. I've installed Phalcon and Phalcon devtools using instruction from [phalconphp.com](http://phalconphp.com).

I've created my project successfully, but PhpStorm shows undefined namespace Phalcon. Website works, but there are so many errors in IDE. I'm afraid it should not looks like this.

Have I done any mistakes while installing framework or creating project?

[image]

Comment: Based on screenshot -- you did not installed phalcon devtools correctly. In any case -- try `File | Invalidate Caches` and restart IDE.

Comment: @LazyOne Invalidate Caches and restart doesn't work. What's wrong in my screen? How should it look like?

Comment: Nothing in particular (nothing that can point to exact answer, I mean) -- it just shows that IDE does not see the stub files (devtools). Where did you put them? Maybe they are outside of the project and not referenced in any other supported way.

Comment: @LazyOne I've installed devtools again using composer and now it works. Thank you!

Comment: if you're using jetbrain's IDE take a look at this plugin: https://plugins.jetbrains.com/plugin/9536-phalcon-auto-complete and let me know if it works

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Download or clone phalcon devtools files from github to your local
https://github.com/phalcon/phalcon-devtools

Open PHPstorm, Under the Project file tree find the "External Libraries" right click and select "Configure PHP Include Paths..." click on "+" in the window then select `phalcon-devtools/scripts/Phalcon` directory from phalcon devtools repo.

Comment: I resolved this method using this method. However, It when I try to make use of the this file, there is an error that the class, 'Config' is not found.

Comment: if you're using jetbrain's IDE take a look at this plugin: https://plugins.jetbrains.com/plugin/9536-phalcon-auto-complete and let me know if it works

Comment: One thing I noticed I am not sure there's a solution for. If you load a custom service from the DI, lets just pretend its the Facebook Api, `$fb = $this->di->get('facebook');` when you type `$fb->` There is no auto suggest -- I have autocomplete and stubs installed in jetbrains.

Comment: sadly, there ain't no `ide/2.0.9` path in current devtools: https://github.com/phalcon/phalcon-devtools/tree/master/ide ; @NishchalGautam your plugin works perfectly, I've added an answer about this, as comments are prone to comment-rot.

Answer (score 0):

As @Nishchal Gautam mentioned [in his comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35529477/phalcon-undefined-namespace-phalcon#comment76622184_35695636), https://plugins.jetbrains.com/plugin/9536-phalcon-auto-complete does exactly this in a more manageable way than downloading the devtools, adding the needed includes by hand in every project etc.